# Chowder without flour

Tags: soup, gluten-free

Is there a gluten free alternative for flour in clam or mussel chowder? The recipe calls for a couple spoonfuls.

Comment: What style of chowder?  ...probably can just omit.

Comment: It's a white muscle chowder that looks like New England clam chowder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to turn soup into stew without using flour?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/114744/what-is-the-best-way-to-turn-soup-into-stew-without-using-flour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, certainly. The flour is only there for thickening. You can use pretty much any flour or starch from a gluten-free grain or tuber, and it will thicken just as well.

Depending on whether you want to add another flavor, you can go for a flour with a strong taste on its own, like buckwheat, and/or whole grain flour. If you don't want that, go for a starch.

As for the amount, do a 1:1 substitute by weight. You can employ it with whatever technique is prescribed in the original - a roux, a slurry, or dusting the solid pieces before adding them, it will all work.

Comment: I use potato starch as a gluten free thickener.